# Android: Gallery with floating image size

Tags: java, android, gallery, android-imageview, image-gallery

For the reference in simple this is what I want to achieve..Even if that's not possible without third parties at least[image] what I want is to make images in the sides smaller and the one in focus to be a bit larger in size then the sides.Thanks also if someone actually know the name of this type of visualization then ill be glad to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a carousel, you may find it under the name "CoverFlow" as well.
A quick search with that name may help you.

Edit :

I found some tutorials/libraries but they are a bit hold, not sure if it's the better way to handle it. For example, here is one with ViewPager :
http://tech.leolink.net/2013/02/create-simple-infinite-carousel-in.html

Be carefull if you chose that way : it uses a FragmentPagerAdapter and can cause you memory issues if you have a lot of fragments. You may have to adapt it with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter but the logic is there.

This one seems a bit better :
https://github.com/dolphinwang/ImageCoverFlow

I don't recommend you to use the ones that extends Gallery (it's deprecated).

Edit 2 :

The final library used : https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow

Comment: You saved my work hours!! This community is actually a brotherhood. waiting for someone to exactly provide a link to some tutorial or else you are my answer!

Comment: I updated my answer. The community helped me a lot too :) Feel free to share the  library you use in the end, if you chose an other one.

Comment: Thank you indeed. I however finally implemented https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow in my application as it was quicker to ad and easier to understand. Your answer is definitely the correct one as it directed me to the accurate search keyword.

Comment: How did you change the size of the individual elements in the coverflow? I searched a lot but could not find any suitable documentation either on stackoverflow or other places? When I change the size by changing the dimen/cover_width/height, the coverflow looks odd and crashes.